# jQuery datatable while using dataSrc in ajax and columns not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$('#treatmentTable').DataTable({
    "bFilter": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "columnDefs": [
        { "orderable": false, "targets": 2 }
    ],
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": { 
        "url": $(".baseurl").val()+'GetAPI.php?func=getTreatment',
        "type": "post",
        "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
           console.log(json.data);
        }  
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "treatment_name", "width":"40%" },
        {
            "data": null,
            "bSortable": false,
            "mRender": function (o) { return '&euro; '+o.treatment_price.replace(".",","); }
        },
        { "data": "treatment_duration"}
    ]
});
```

I am using jquery datatable, while i m using columns and ajax dataSrc at that time error is showing like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

From ajax its returns: 
    `{"draw":"1","recordsTotal":10,"recordsFiltered":8,"data":[{"treatment_id":"27","treatment_name":"ttt","treatment_price":"22.10","treatment_duration":"15","barberid":"94"}}]}`

Looking for help.

Comment: Have you tried with success function rather than dataSrc in ajax?

Comment: Yes i used it but while i m using success function datatable not loading `processing` label is displaying

Comment: What is the output of your console.log() in dataSrc callback function

Comment: @R.K.Saini i just edit my question, you can see what i can get from ajax in console.log()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second column you use render option to render it, In your render function you pass only 1 parameter which represent data field not the full row, So to get full row you need to pass 3 parameter to function 
check here https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Change it with this

```
"mRender": function ( data, type, o) { return '&euro; '+o.treatment_price.replace(".",","); }
```

**EDIT**

You see processing lable because you are not returning data from your dataSrc function

```
"ajax": {
    "url": 'upload.php',
    "type": "post",
    "dataSrc": function (json) {
        console.log(json.data);
        return json.data; // you need to return data array here
    }
}
```

**FULL**

```
    $('#treatmentTable').DataTable({
        "bFilter": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "columnDefs": [
            {"orderable": false, "targets": 2}
        ],
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": 'upload.php',
            "type": "post",
            "dataSrc": function (json) {
                console.log(json.data);
                return json.data;
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "treatment_name", "width": "40%"},
            {
                "data": null,
                "bSortable": false,
                "mRender": function (d,t,o) {
                    return '&euro; ' + o.treatment_price.replace(".", ",");
                }
            },
            {"data": "treatment_duration"}
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: which version of datatable you are using?

Comment: I don't know because i m using that library since 2 years